# why fputcsv produce extra blank column in csv

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I am trying to remove unnecessary column from my csv. What i do is read from current csv and use fputcsv to produce a new one. However, the data is mess up because fputcsv add extra blank column just before `$data[21]`. Below is my code

```
$file_path = 'test.csv';
$file_output = 'new.csv';
if (file_exists($file_path) && filesize($file_path) > 0) {
    if (false !== ($read_file = fopen($file_path, 'r'))) {
        $output_file = fopen($file_output, 'w');
        while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($read_file))) {
            $outputData = array($data[1], $data[6], $data[19], $data[20],
                $data[21]);
            fputcsv($output_file, $outputData);

        }

    }
    fclose($read_file);
    fclose($output_file);

}
```

Comment: Do all the referenced array positions exist? var_dump them out to make 100% sure

Comment: yes i did... the array position before write out to the csv are correct. I manually var_dump it out and checked. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post an example of the CSV data that's being output?

Comment: "Gaash Lighting Ltd",G2,"Kibbutz Gaash",,,"
"

Comment: Yikes... your PHP shows putting 5 columns, you but the output is 8 columns. Did you make sure you delete the output file (`new.csv`) between runs?

Comment: Thanks let me try it

Comment: ahhh... it works now .. thank you so much .. if you put this as answer i can marks this .. thank you so much again

Comment: Answer added with a suggestion to unset the output file if it already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the different column counts, it appears that the file needs deleted before you run your code. You might want to `unset` the file at the start of the execution.

```
if (file_exists($file_output)) {
    unset($file_output);
}

// continue with getting and populating CSV
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have mentioned correct sequence of array here:

```
 $outputData = array($data[1], $data[6], $data[19], $data[20], 
                          $data[21]);
```

If data index will not found/defined then [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) will add extra column into new csv.

Comment: Hi what i did was var_dump $data variable so I could see the pointing in the array and pick the necessary position in array to write out. So there is no way one of the column i pick above is not defined. It is very strange

Comment: Do this way then:                                                                                          while(false !== ($data = fgetcsv($read_file))){
          $outputData[0] = $data[1];
          $outputData[1] = $data[6];
          $outputData[2] = $data[19];
          $outputData[3] = $data[20];
          $outputData[4] = $data[21];
        }
        fputcsv($output_file, $outputData);

Comment: Sure .. then let me try that

Comment: the last column it also get append with " and in the new line get append with with another " .. This is so strange i never seen this happen before

Comment: Its really strange!! Try by adding ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

Comment: Try by adding delimiter:  fputcsv($output_file, $outputData, ',');